# label value in custom tableview cell is changing while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Label value in custom tableview cell is changing while scrolling the tableview

```
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = (CheckOutCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // If there is no cell to reuse, create a new one
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CheckOutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];



    }

    cell.delegate = self;

    CheckOutGroup * checkOut=_cartArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.name.text=checkOut.name;
    cell.size.text=checkOut.size;
    cell.priceValue=checkOut.price ;
    [array addObject:checkOut.dictionary];
    [itemIdArray addObject:checkOut.itemId];
    cell.price.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Price:%@%@",self.currValue,checkOut.price];

    cell.quantity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Qty:%d",1];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sqwip.ignivainfotech.net/%@",checkOut.image]]];
        cell.checkOutImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    NSUserDefaults *storeDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [storeDefaults setObject:self.currValue forKey:@"cur"];

    cell.increaseBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    val=[checkOut.price intValue];

    if (check==0) {
        check=check+[checkOut.price intValue];
    }
    else
    check=check+[checkOut.price intValue];


    self.totalPrice.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TotalPrice:%@%d",self.currValue,check];


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: can you be more specific by "changing while scrolling"? Does this mean that the data changes once the cell scrolls off the screen and then scrolls back onto the screen? Or do you mean as soon as the tableview scrolls it changes?

Comment: Your code looks a little odd - it is unusual to perform calculations on instance variables (check, array, itemIdArray) in cellForIndexPath - this method will be called as the table is redrawn. You should perform calculations elsewhere and just provide the already calculated data into the cell in this method

Comment: datais changing once the cell scrolls off the screen and then scrolls back onto the screen.If I scroll up top cell values are changing and if I scroll down down cell values are changing.

Answer (score 0):

When a cell needs to be displayed (IE scrolling back onto the screen) the tableview controller is going to look at the **data source** and fire the some of its methods so it can display the correct information. In short its going to recall this method every time a cell needs to be displayed:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If the cell is **changing** its because the **data source** is changing! I suggest placing a break point inside cellForRow and make sure the data from your:

```
CheckOutGroup * checkOut=_cartArray[indexPath.row];
```

or whatever is correct for the right cell before and after scrolling. If it is different and it shouldn't be, possibly you are grabbing the wrong data from the URL on the next pass or your indexes are getting out of place.

Comment: yes,I'm changing the label value with increase button in cell.when I'm scrolling then the label is taking the value  from the CheckOutGroup.

Comment: I don't understand, if you have a integer that you want to be able to increment with a UIButton in the cell, you need to update the data source aswell. Then CheckOutGroup needs to grab that new updated value whenever cellForRow is called?

Answer (score 0):

```
It's because of re-useability. Since UITableView reuse its cell on scrolling. To resolve this just make your cell nil.
Try this on CellForRowAtIndexPath:-

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = (CheckOutCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell)
       cell = nil
    // If there is no cell to reuse, create a new one
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CheckOutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
```